# Printing list in without sequence operator

Tags: list, printing, ocaml

Want to print list without using sequence operator:-

This is my program, I want to make this program without ";" operator and without using "let" for assigning variables !

```
let rec print_row = function
[]->()
|h::t -> print_int h; Printf.printf(" "); print_row t;;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to implement a generic approach for applying functions over any type of lists. You can go about this in the following manner using List.map:

```
print_string (String.concat " " (List.map string_of_int [1;2;3;4]));;
```

You can learn more about List.map [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a school assignment, so I'll just make some suggestions.

If you're trying to reformulate the function into more idiomatic OCaml, one thing to think of is the functions in the `List` module. In particular, you could write a function that does what you want to do for each element of the list, then look in the `List` module for a way to call a function for every element of a list.

If you just want to eliminate the `;` operator (which is pretty unlikely I realize), you can always rewrite `a; b` as `let _ = a in b`.